# PHP Remove html link tag from a string where the hypertext in new line

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
$linkString="The Following is a link to google <a class='links' href='http://google.com'>

http://google.com
</a>
";
```

In this string the hypertext of the html link in new line. I want to remove and may be replace all of the link (its html tag and the hypertext) from the string, so I tried the following:

```
<?php
$linkString="The Following is a link to google <a class='links' href='http://google.com'>

http://google.com
</a>
";

//Remove link tag:

echo preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/','',$linkString);
```

However, the above example prints out:

```
The Following is a link to google 

http://google.com
```

This is an online DEMO: http://codepad.org/whw81bwa

I want to know a regex that able to remove all the link (tag and hypertext)

Comment: Could I know why down vote? It is not duplicated question and I tried for something.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function?

Comment: I don't want strip all tags. I just want to strip the `a` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using regex, make effective use of [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to do this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);  

foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $tag) {
   $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable idea, but I found another regex that allow replacing the link too. It is shown in my answer.

Comment: I trired to use your solution and I get this error:
`Strict Standards: Non-static method DOMDocument::loadHTML() should not be called statically in E:\XXX\viewtopic.php on line 1422`
Plus UTF8 issue in render text. @hwnd

Comment: See update and probably need to append a meta header to force UTF-8 interpretation.

Comment: I found using `mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");` in the `'loadHTML` method will solve the encoding issue [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154528/how-to-force-xpath-to-use-utf8). However, is there a way to `replaceChild` instead of `removeChild`? @hwnd

Comment: Oh, sorry, Indeed there is already a method called `replaceChild`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex solve the issue:

```
/(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)<\/a>/'
```

So,

```
<?php
$linkString="The Following is a link to google <a class='links' href='http://google.com'>

http://google.com
</a>
";

//Remove link tag:

echo preg_replace('/(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)<\/a>/','A Hidden Link',$linkString);
```